# display: inline element with multiple lines of text not correct height in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, absolute

There is a `blockquote` set to `display: inline`, and the text wraps to multiple lines. In Safari and Chrome, the height (or rather the "space" that the browser sees it taking up vertically) is the sum of all lines put together (including padding, line-height, font-size, etc).

However in Firefox, only the first line seems to be "used" to determine absolute positioning coordinates (note in the image below Firefox is actually reporting all the lines' combined height/space). This is causing inconsistencies for a child element that is positioned absolutely according to this inline element's height.

The quote images are background images within a `pseudo::before` element on the `blockquote` inline element (which is `position: relative`). This unique combo allows the trailing quote to 'float' precisely where the last word ends on the last line -- at least in -webkit- browsers. The `right` and `bottom` coordinates are based off the current end of the line at the last word, instead of the containing block space (which by the way is very cool).

Why is Firefox different in this, and is there a workaround that works with display: inline (a requirement for the text-highlighting effect)?

**Safari/Chrome:**

[image: Safari/Chrome]
**Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

And here's the generalized code:

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 1.333em;
    line-height: 2.167em;
    color: #4DC3FF;
    box-shadow: -0.5em 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0.5em 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    border-top: 0.2em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.222em solid transparent;
    display: inline;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
}

blockquote:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4.708em;
    right: -4.708em;
    top: -1.867em;
    bottom: -1.903em;
    background-image: url("quotes-left.svg"), url("quotes-right.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 3.708em 3.333em, 3.708em 3.333em;
    background-position: 0px 0px, 100% 100%;
}
```

And you can see this in action here:

http://www.demo.com/ehome/index.php?eventid=29414&#what-they-say

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with **box-decoration-break**, but I believe that it means that each fragment (line) is treated separately. Firefox may be adding both :before and :after to the first fragment.

Comment: @bobdye the same described behavior occurs with or without Mozilla's `box-decoration-break`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem.

Firefox relates to the very first line for absolute positioned elements.

Solved it by changing the position of pseudo-elements from absolute to relative one.
Here is an example:

```css
.quote {
   text-align: center;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }

 .quote q {
   position: relative;
   display: inline;
   quotes: none;
 }
 
 .quote q span {
   white-space: normal;
 }

 .quote::after,
 .quote::before {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   content: '"';
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <q><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</span></q>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using `display: contents;` on the parent element.